# use VPN to prevent setting Port Fowarding in Router?

Tags: vpn, port-forwarding

Right now I have 2 branches in Asia; one is in Malaysia and another in Vietnam.

Unfortunately both are communicating using port 6901-6999 and port 1433.  Because of the long distance between the two I am afraid there will be communication problems so I'm using a VPN to avoid using port forwarding at the router.  Can the VPN avoid or pass through the router?  Both computer are in same network.  I think there is no need to set port forwarding any more, right?

I'm using Ubuntu server to host VPN.

Or is there any method to prevent setting port forwarding in the router?

1. Using VPN on both computer, we only setting port on VPN Server.  We do not need to set any port forwarding in router, correct or not?
2. If #1 is incorrect, do you have any ideas for avoiding port forwarding in the router other than using Hamachi?

Comment: Your question was a bit unclear.  I've edited it to try and clear it up a bit.  Please correct my edit if there is something that is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a Static Site-to-Site VPN tunnel between your 2 LAN's. This will involve fowarding the VPN ports

The following ports will need to be fowarded depending on what type of VPN you will use :

```
PPTP:
TCP Port number=1723  

L2TP:
UDP Port Number=500    
UDP Port Number=4500   

SSTP:
TCP Port number=443
```

Comment: my port forwarding are using port 6901 until 6999, we do not need to setting this port on VPN server? can explain clearly? and i m using OpenVPN for VPn server

Comment: I dont think you need to set the 69xx ports on your VPN server for it to work properly.

Comment: can provide any setup a Static Site-to-Site VPN setup procedure?